# Spammy structured data Issue (Markup Ok but considered spammy by Google)

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I received the message in Search Console about spammy structured data regarding one of my websites. Mind you - It's an older website that has not been up to the standards.

So I  had all the error and warnings fixed and I submitted website for reconsideration. Reconsideration has been refused. Problem is I do not know why? Website pass the structured data testing tool test. There is no errors or warnings. At the moment markup is done within HTML ( not json-ld). Could someone take a look and advise me what I can do to have it fixed according to google guidelines and manual action removed.

I', not so sure if this is important or not, but index page is not the only one to contain markup for LocalBusiness. There are more pages similar to the index one, based on different location.

Website in question is http://www.man-van.biz

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: For your information is not. Website link has been placed here so the people can lookup structured data. And honestly we all know that there is no SEO juice coming from Stack overflow.  So  I see no issue here. Btw problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. Problem was with duplicated schema markup on aggregate ratings (the same feedback's on all pages). Once I removed it from other pages and kept it only on index page and fix some other issues with markup reconsideration request has been approved and manual action removed.